# Wrap text when pasting with another text in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

I want, when I am pasting links to a cell, that the text would automatically be wrapped with another text.

For instance, I have this link copied in my clipboard: `http://example.com`. When I paste it in a cell, I want it automatically to be wrapped by another text:

```
<div class="text"><a href="http://example.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Example</a></div>
```

The output of that csv is rendered in html.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using Excel formulas. I think it's the quickest solution, if you are not planning to to this task repetitively a lot of times.

If you paste your link in `A1`, in `B1` I would put this:

```
="<div class=""text""><a href="""&A1&""" rel=""noopener"" target=""_blank"">Example</a></div>"
```

When you are done pasting references and making formulas, you can copy the cell with the formula and paste only the value on top of it. Then delete the original reference. This way you will not have formulas in cells.

Comment: The final result of the csv is 4 columns that will be rendered as html, in your solution before i save the file i have to delete A column, when i do that B column goes to starting point.

Comment: You must paste values on column B before deleting the column A

Comment: Was the answer helpful?